# Sydroid direct RTSP URL

Tags: html, video-streaming, rtsp

I'm playing around with Spydroid a bit and wants to display the RTSP stream in an web browser, preferably in HTML5 to be able to view the stream on mobile devices. I've been looking around quite alot and it seems that RTSP works great with HTML5, the problem is that most RTSP URLs look something like this:

rtsp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/videofile.mov

So my question is, how can I point to a similar RTSP URL using Spydroid or is there another solution?

(The RTSP URL that works e.g. in VLC for me is rtsp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:XXXX but can't figure out how to use that URL with different HTML5 video players...)